# How to control label positions in tikz-euclide

Tags: positioning, tkz-euclide

My goal in trying to learn `tkz-euclide` is so that I can be able to get an arbitrary point from a circle and define the other elements of my figure from that. So far, from what I can understand from the examples given in the manual (I don't know any French), I came up with the following code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} % Defines a point
    \tkzGetRandPointOn[circle=center O radius 1.5cm]{A} % Gets random point of the circle with center at O and radius 1.5cm
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A) % Draws the circle
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 100](A) % Defines a point...
        \tkzGetPoint{C} % named C
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 78](A) % Defines a point...
        \tkzGetPoint{B} % named B
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B,C) % Draws dots
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,B B,A A,O O,C) % Draws the segments
    \tkzLabelPoints(O,A,B,C)    % Labels the points
    %\node [below] at (O) {$O$};
    %\node [above] at (A) {$A$};
    %\node [left] at (B) {$B$};
    %\node [left] at (C) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is nice. But the random positioning of the points screws up the positioning of the labels. (Try compiling several times to see.) I have tried setting up the nodes through the usual `\node` commands but I still end up with the same problem.How can I control the behavior of the labels so that they would not overlap with other elements of the figure?

### Edit

I read this mod comment on my list of questions: *Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?* Indeed, I have considered accepting an answer since the solution now looks trivial with `tikz` but I would still like to see a `tkz-euclide`-based solution, too. So I thought I would prolong accepting an answer for a short while. So how about starting a bounty instead? Well, why not?

Comment: It may be worth comparing the answer below with [mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71175/9467).

Comment: Yeah. I saw that. I left a comment in that question too. Not the package that I am asking for but very well done in so short a code.

Comment: It is not the link you gave a comment to.

Comment: I'm lost. Which link?

Comment: The link in my first comment.

Comment: Oh, I missed it earlier. Looks great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could compute a point radially outside of the circle at each point to place the node:

[image] [image]
[image] [image]

The label for the origin is placed at a point opposite of the `(B)` node.  A slightly better solution would be to compute the angle midway between `(OA)` and `(OC)` and place the origin label at a 180 degree offset from that.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,1){O} % Defines the point at which the origin is located
    \tkzGetRandPointOn[circle=center O radius 1.5cm]{A} % Gets random point of the circle with center at O and radius 1.5cm
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A) % Draws the circle
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 100](A) % Defines a point...
    \tkzGetPoint{C} % named C
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 78](A) % Defines a point...
    \tkzGetPoint{B} % named B
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B,C) % Draws dots
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,B B,A A,O O,C) % Draws the segments

    % compute vectors of each point form the origin
    \coordinate (OA) at ($(A)-(O)$);
    \coordinate (OB) at ($(B)-(O)$);
    \coordinate (OC) at ($(C)-(O)$);

    \node [red] at ($(O)+1.15*(OA)$)  {A};
    \node [red] at ($(O)+1.15*(OB)$)  {B};
    \node [red] at ($(O)+1.15*(OC)$)  {C};
    \node [red] at ($(B)-1.15*(OB)$)  {O};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put each label outside the circle but on the corresponding bisector will be more beautiful (in my opinion).

Comment: @GarbageCollector: Not sure I understand. To me, the correct place to put the label is along the radial line from the origin, which is what is done here.

Comment: OK. For this special case (as opposed to arbitrary polygon), putting the labels radially outward makes sense!

Comment: There is still the old trouble with that center. I tried moving it to another point with nonzero coordinates but the result was a mess.

Comment: @hpesoj626: Have corrected for an arbitrary origin.

Comment: This already very good. But see that second figure on the top figures? How can we get that label to not overlap with any of the segments? It seems like the only recourse is to run several compiles to get no overlaps.

Comment: @hpesoj626: As mentioned in the **Notes** section, I was only addressing the points around the circle. But a simple way to place the origin label would be opposite of `(OB)` -- I will update the solution for that.

Comment: more concise : `\path (O) -- ($ (B) + 0.15*($(B)-(O)$) $) node{B};`

Answer (score 3):

I added a part of my answer in the next version of `tkz-euclide`.

```
\tkzAutoLabelPoints needs a point called **center** and a coefficient called **with**, this number represents  a percentage of the distance between the point and the center. By default it's 0.15

\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/@tkzautolab/.cd,
    center/.store in    = \tkz@center,
    with/.store in      = \tkz@with,
    with                = 0.15,
   /@tkzautolab/.search also   = {/tikz},
}
\def\tkzAutoLabelPoints{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@AutoLabelPoints}{%
                                         \tkz@AutoLabelPoints[]}}% 
\def\tkz@AutoLabelPoints[#1](#2){%
\begingroup 
\pgfqkeys{/@tkzautolab}{#1} 
 \foreach \point in {#2}{
 \path (\tkz@center) -- ($ (\point) + \tkz@with*($(\point)-(\tkz@center)$) $) node{$\point$};}
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,1){O} % Defines the point at which the origin is located
    \tkzGetRandPointOn[circle=center O radius 1.5cm]{A} % Gets random point of the circle with center at O and radius 1.5cm
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A) % Draws the circle
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 100](A) % Defines a point...
    \tkzGetPoint{C} % named C
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 78](A) % Defines a point...
    \tkzGetPoint{B} % named B
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B,C) % Draws dots
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,B B,A A,O O,C) % Draws the segments
    \tkzAutoLabelPoints[center=O,red](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,1){O} % Defines the point at which the origin is located
    \tkzGetRandPointOn[circle=center O radius 1.5cm]{A} % Gets random point of the circle with center at O and radius 1.5cm
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A) % Draws the circle
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 100](A) % Defines a point...
    \tkzGetPoint{C} % named C
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 78](A) % Defines a point...
    \tkzGetPoint{B} % named B
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B,C) % Draws dots
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,B B,A A,O O,C) % Draws the segments
    \tkzDefBarycentricPoint(O=1,A=1,B=1,C=1)
     \tkzAutoLabelPoints[center=tkzPointResult,with=.3,red](O,A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]