# How to automatically place points names of a polygon on the bisector lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, pst-eucl, tkz-euclide

Let us consider the simpler one which is a triangle. According to the `pst-eucl`,

[image]

the point names will be placed on the bisector lines.

The below example is contradictory to the above statement.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\pstVerb
{
    /rv {rand 36000 mod 100 div} def % random number from 0.00 to 359.99
}

\begin{document}

\psLoop{30}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscircle[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=lightgray]{2}
    \pstTriangle[linejoin=2](!2 rv PtoC){A}(!2 rv PtoC){B}(!2 rv PtoC){C}%
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Now let us consider any polygon. How to automatically place points names of a polygon on the bisector lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

needs the current `pst-eucl.tex|pro` from http://texnik.dante.de/

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\psforeach{\Angle}{0,10,..,360}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pscircle[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=lightgray]{2}
\pstTriangle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!30!white,
             opacity=0.4,linejoin=2](2;145){A}(2;195){B}(2;\Angle){C}%
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It only works for `\pstTriangle` or it also works for any polygon generated by `\pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon](){}...(){}`?

Comment: at the moment only for the triangle ...

Answer (score 3):

Not a reliable solution because the labels are sometimes inside the polygon.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\pstVerb
{
    /rv {rand 36000 mod 100 div} def % random number from 0.00 to 359.99
}

\begin{document}

\psLoop{30}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscircle[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=lightgray]{2}
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon,PointName=none,linejoin=2]
    (!0 0){A}
    (!2 rv PtoC){B}
    (!2 rv PtoC){C}
    (!2 rv PtoC){D}
    \psset{MarkAngleRadius=0,LabelSep=0.25}
    \pstMarkAngle{D}{A}{B}{\tiny$A$}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{\tiny$B$}
    \pstMarkAngle{B}{C}{D}{\tiny$C$}
    \pstMarkAngle{C}{D}{A}{\tiny$D$}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Please edit if you want to make it reliable.

Comment: When the labels are placed inside the polygon, you can manually put them outside the polygon by reversing the order, for example from `{D}{A}{B}` to `{B}{A}{D}`.